# Better way to compare images in Python

Tags: python, opencv, sift, orb

I am using Scikits SSIM to calculate how similar 2 pictures are, and it is working fine for one exception. When there is a lot of white pixels (lets say its a pure white background with a very simple black outlined shape) it will say they are very similar when the actual shape is in fact very different.

I tried looking for other questions about this but couldn't find one that accurately answered my question.

Some code:

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import numpy as np
import cv2

# With SSIM, compares image A to image B, and returns the result.
def compare_images(imageA, imageB):
    return compare_ssim(imageA, imageB)

# Loads an image with a given filepath with imread.
def load_images(filepath):
    picture = cv2.imread(filepath)

    # Convert the images to grayscale
    return cv2.cvtColor(picture, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# compare the images
original = load_images("images/images.png")
contrast = load_images("images/download.png")

result = compare_images(original, contrast)
print(result)
```

Mind you, I am just a Python novice. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: You can try SIFT, SURF in opencv for feature extraction and similar image matching.

Comment: Have you tried different similarity measures like PSNR?

Comment: I've been trying sift but it doesn't work with my OpenCV without enabling nonfree, and I'm getting a bit stuck on that, any help?

Comment: PSNR will not work I think, as I dont want to be comparing pixels like MSE does sadly.